# Qt drawing a ring / circle with a hole

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I need to draw a circle with QPainter. When I used drawEllipse function like :

```
void UserClass::Draw(QPainter &painter) {

    painter.save();
    painter.setBrush( GetColor() );
    QPoint centerPosition = GetCenterPosition();
    painter.drawEllipse( centerPosition, m_CircleOuterRadius, m_CircleOuterRadius);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
    painter.drawEllipse( centerPosition, m_CircleInnerRadius, m_CircleInnerRadius);
    painter.restore();  
}
```

Unfortunately result is not what I desired. I want to have inner circle not be filled. That is why I put alpha value as zero but ofcourse it didn't work. How can I have a circle which is not until a certain radius with qt ?

[image]

Comment: *"ofcourse it didn't work"* is not a problem statement. Please be specific.

Comment: I'd say better approach here would be create QPainterPath and use QPainetr::fillPath

Comment: You need empty brush `painter.setBrush(QBrush());` or C++11 style: `painter.setBrush({});` and some pen `painter.setPen(GetColor());`.

Comment: @MarekR But an empty brush will not give me the out part neither I guess. Therefore wouldnt be  what I need,

Comment: Outer part is drawn using a pen. I've wrote about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a `QPainterPath` then add the two circles to it via `addEllipse()`, the outer first, then the inner. This will effectively give you a shape that is the outer circle with the inner circle punched as a hole.

Then you fill the painter path with a green brush, which will result in a hollow ring. Afterwards, if you want the white outlines, you can stroke the path with a white pen as well.

Also note that the painter path can be created only once and stored for reuse instead of creating it anew every time you redraw.